# How to write a bash script to run commands in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, rails-console

I need to wirte a bash script to run commands in my rails console, the commands are : `Station.create(......)`

```
  #!/bin/bash

   rails console
```

After this line i have no ideas. i tried `echo "Station.create(...)`, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 7):

You want `runner`.

```
#/bin/bash

# Maybe need to prefix with `bundle exec`
rails runner 'Station.create(…)'
```

Comment: when i try to create a new station in rails console  it does not create a new record. `#!/bin/bash
rails runner 'Station.create(cd:"BK",station: "bla", icao: "BKBK", iata:"BKK", synop:"77777", lat:"55.55", lon:"555.55", elev: "5", mflag: "K", nexrad:"K", country_code:"BK", plotting:"5")'
exit 0
`

Comment: That I can't help with other than to try it in the console and look for errors.